# SSRS LookupSet with more than one Dataset in report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to use LookupSet in SSRS so that I concatenate a list into one textbox.

```
dataset1
TYPE      |DESC
fruit     |apple
fruit     |orange
furit     |grape
```

Results in

```
apple; orange; grape
```

Here is my ssrs textbox expression

```
=JOIN( lookupset( Fields!TYPE.Value,Fields!TYPE.Value, Fields!DESC.Value, "dataset1"), "; ")
```

It works as expected, until I add a second dataset to my report.  The dataset does not have any of the same fieldnames used by my lookup expression. I do not change my textbox expression.  My lookupset function is still referring to dataset1.  I just get the error:

```
 The Value expression for the text box ‘TEXTBOX1’ refers directly to the 
 field ‘TYPE’ without specifying a dataset aggregate.  When the report
 contains multiple datasets, field references outside of a data region must 
 be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope.
```

When I delete the second dataset, everything is works.

How can I use the `LookupSet` function in a report with multiple datasets?

Comment: Is this in a table or a textbox? It sounds as if the text box isn't connected to a data source by being in a table. I don't see how you would be able to do it without using a table. Use a table using **Dataset1** and Group By **TYPE**.